# get FormData call ajax to symfony 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, symfony4

My code js is:

```js
fetch(img).then(response => response.blob()) //img is canvas with method toBlob('image/png')
  .then(blob => {
    console.log(blob)
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileName", blob, "file.ext");
    return fetch("/sendImg", {
      method: "POST",
      fd
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.ok)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Symfony not working with any things:

```
 $_REQUEST['fileName']) || isset($_FILES['fileName']) || $request->files->get('fileName')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the body property in your request, because now you are not sending the form data, you are setting a **fd** property

```
fetch("/sendImg", {
      method: "POST",
      body: fd // here
})
```